# is there a propper way to concatenate the following chain of observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I want to execute an observable after a chain of observables completes. This chain of observables is an array converted in an observable. So I cannot make a simple concatenation because it will get executed every time.

I have used the following approach using skipUnitl(last()) but it gets executed when the first chain of observables emits its first value. At the end I would need an operator that allowed me to execute the second observable once the first chain of observables is completed.

This is how I have it right now and it doesn't work:

```
const typDb$ = Observable.from(this.typificationsShowed)
      .pipe(
        concatMap((response: QueuesTypificationShowed) => {
          return Observable.from(response.ouList);
        })
      )
      .pipe(
        //Hacemos un observable por cada vez que se ha añadido la tipificacion
        concatMap((response: OuCount) => {
          return Observable.from(
            Array.from({ length: response.count }, (i) => response.ou)
          );
        }),
        concatMap((response: QueuesTypificationOu) => {
          const e: AttentionTypification = new AttentionTypification();
          e.queuesTypificationId = response.queuesTypificationId;
          e.attentionId = this.attentionService.actualAttention.attentionId;
          return this.attentionTypificationService.create(e);
        }))
      

    let typificationsOrchestra: Array<Typification> = this.queuesTypificationService.setOrchestraTypifications();

    const typOrchestra$ =  this.queueManagerService.setTypifications(typificationsOrchestra, this.currentUser)
      .pipe(
        concatMap((response: UserStatus) => {
          console.log(response);
          return this.queueManagerService.endAttention(response);
        }),
        tap((response:UserStatus)=> {
          this.queueManagerService.userSource.next(response);
        })
      )
     
    //No ejecutamos el observable hasta que se ha emitido el último valor del observable typDb$
    typOrchestra$.skipUntil(typDb$.pipe(last()))
    .subscribe(...)
```

So typOrchestra$ should get executed once all the members of the typDb$ have been treated.

I have succeded in doing this by subscribing to typDb$ and emiting a value of a subject in complete(). Then in typOrchestra$ I listen to this subject and when it emits the proper value the chain continues.

```
const typDb$ = Observable.from(this.typificationsShowed)
  .pipe(
  concatMap((response: QueuesTypificationShowed) => {
    return Observable.from(response.ouList);
  })
  )
  .pipe(
  //Hacemos un observable por cada vez que se ha añadido la tipificacion
  concatMap((response: OuCount) => {
    return Observable.from(
      Array.from({ length: response.count }, (i) => response.ou)
    );
  }),
  concatMap((response: QueuesTypificationOu) => {
    const e: AttentionTypification = new AttentionTypification();
    e.queuesTypificationId = response.queuesTypificationId;
    e.attentionId = this.attentionService.actualAttention.attentionId;
    return this.attentionTypificationService.create(e);
  })).subscribe(() => {

  }, error => {

  }, () => {
    endAttentionSource.next("complete");
  }
  );

//No ejecutamos el observable hasta que se ha completado el observable que inserta las tipificaciones en la base de datos.
endAttSubscription = endAttention
.pipe(
  filter((response: string) => response == 'complete'),
  //Now it concatenates the observables of typOrchestra$
```

But this approach doesn't seem to me as a clean one. Do you know how to do it in a propper manner?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `concat` here, which will only subscribe to `typOrchestra$` once `typDb$` completes:

```js
import { concat } from 'rxjs';

concat(typDb$, typOrchestra$)
  .subscribe(value => {
    // Handle value
  })
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but this approach doesn't work. When the first member of the array of typDB$ is treated, meaning this "return this.attentionTypificationService.create(e)" gets called for the first time, typOrchestra$ is executed. This is the approach I had already tried unsuccesfully.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, the following should work:

```ts
const typDb$ = from(this.typificationsShowed).pipe(
  concatMap((response: QueuesTypificationShowed) => response.ouList),
  //Hacemos un observable por cada vez que se ha añadido la tipificacion
  concatMap((response: OuCount) => Array.from(
    { length: response.count }, 
    i => response.ou
  )),
  concatMap((response: QueuesTypificationOu) => {
    const e: AttentionTypification = new AttentionTypification();
    e.queuesTypificationId = response.queuesTypificationId;
    e.attentionId = this.attentionService.actualAttention.attentionId;
    return this.attentionTypificationService.create(e);
  })
);

const typOrchestra$ = defer(() => {
  let typificationsOrchestra: Array<Typification> = this.queuesTypificationService.setOrchestraTypifications();

  return this.queueManagerService.setTypifications(
    typificationsOrchestra, 
    this.currentUser
  ).pipe(
    concatMap((response: UserStatus) => {
      console.log(response);
      return this.queueManagerService.endAttention(response);
    }),
    tap((response:UserStatus) => {
      this.queueManagerService.userSource.next(response);
    })
  )
});
```

That being said, there's a lot of kind of unorthodox "stuff" happening off-screen here. If typOrchestra$ is somehow subscribed to elsewhere or your queueManagerService is doing something strange, then the right solution is hard to tell from what you've written here.

It looks like you're trying to ignore typOrchestra$ until typDb$ completes. That's bit different, but something like this might work:

```ts
typOrchestra$.pipe(
  skipUntil(typDb$.pipe(
    filter(_ => false),
    s => concat(s, of(1))
  ))
).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: "It looks like you're trying to ignore typOrchestra$ until typDb$ completes" That's precisely what I am looking for. But skipUntil skips until the first value is emited, so it is not yet completed.

Comment: @PolSotosCano Oh, right. Filter `_ => false` should do it. Fixed it in my example.